# Get Countries from specific continent using Faker Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, faker

I am generating a random country name using the api `Faker` but I wanted to specific from either europian or american continent but couldn't find a parameter to add. I tried to explore with the Available locals but couldn't link both to get a country from a specific locals. Any idea how?

```
from faker.config import AVAILABLE_LOCALES
from faker import Faker
print([local for local in AVAILABLE_LOCALES]) #just to check the avaialable locals
fake = Faker()
print(fake.country()) # want country from specific continent
```

Comment: It seems that faker provides countries in a basic tuple without additional information ([see here](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/providers/address/en/__init__.py)). So i don't think there's a way to do this only with faker.

Comment: I do seem to agree with you because I already checked their documentation and couldn't find a way. Thank you for confirming that.